# windows phone 7.1 application hangs in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I am a newbie for WP.My windows phone 7.1 application works in windows phone 7 but the application hangs when I open it in windows phone 8. I also want to know how to test the application for compatibility in both windows phone 7 and windows phone 8.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the app in a WP8 device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The applications built for Windows Phone 7.x should work on Windows Phone 8. However,some applications may not work properly and you should definitely test your application on Windows Phone 8 devices.

You could also maintain two versions of your application: one for Windows Phone 7 and one for Windows Phone 8. You will be able to upgrade Windows Phone 7 project to Windows Phone 8 project, but you cannot downgrade. The best thing to do is to create a new Windows Phone 7 project and move all files from the WP8 project to the new one.

Fore more refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206997(v=vs.105).aspx)

Hope it helps!